# Exception or null checkin? What is more ellegant?

Tags: java

Lets say I have html form and controller which handle that form. Controller starts a Service, which takes 2 arguments. Arguments may be null, if user send empty fields form.

Now... how to handle that situation? What is more ellegant? I prefer pass this values from controller to service without checking if value is null in controller layer.

> **First approach - checking null values at Controller layer**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String borrowBook(@RequestParam(value = "borrower_id", required = false) Long borrowerId,
            @RequestParam(value = "book_id", required = false) Long bookId){

        if (borrowerId != null && bookId != null)
            borrowService.createBorrow(bookId, borrowerId);

        return "redirect:index.html";
    }
```

> **Second approach - passing values to service and cheking exception at cotnroller layer**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String borrowBook(@RequestParam(value = "borrower_id", required = false) Long borrowerId,
            @RequestParam(value = "book_id", required = false) Long bookId){

        try {
            borrowService.createBorrow(bookId, borrowerId);
        } catch(CreateBorrowException e){
            //Do something
        }

        return "redirect:index.html";
    }
```

> **Third approach - handling exception at Service layer so controller doesn't actually know if exception occur or not.**

```
Service :
public void createBorrow(Long bookId, Long borrowerId) {
        try {
            Book book = getBookFromId(bookId);
            Borrower borrower = getBorrowerFromId(borrowerId);
            Borrow borrow = new Borrow(book, borrower);
            markBookAsRented(book);
            setBorrowIntoEntities(borrow, book, borrower);
            persistEntities(borrow, book, borrower);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

What do you think? I prefer option 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's *normal* for the caller to send an empty form, that's usually a use case for a `null` check.

If it's *unusual* (an error, e.g., something *exceptional*) for the caller to send an empty form, that's usually a use case for allowing an exception (and possibly dealing with it, or allowing it to propagate to the caller).

Which is more "elegant" is a matter of style.

Note that while entering `try` blocks isn't expensive, allowing an exception to be thrown is (expensive = runtime and [temporary] memory cost). But of course, unless you're throwing hundreds of thousands exceptions in a second, it doesn't matter which is faster.

Comment: Thank you. I consider stuation when it is unusual. So it it normall to validate form parameters at Service layer?

Comment: @G.Spansky: That would make sense to me. I don't use the framework you're using, so I can't speak to common practices specific to that framework, but in general I'd handle it at the high rather than low level.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest approach as follows:

- Front end -  you can check in your `javascript` for empty check.
  because if your client side code is validating same then you can have
  more options to deal with it. And you will able to avoid server hit.
- Back end- if you want to additionally add server side validation for
  same then add it in your service layer because all business logic
  should be in service class; you can follow this.

  1)using if statement - return `boolean` value to take decision in controller

  2) just add throw Create borrower exception to service class's method and handle it in controller using try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I think such choices are very subjective and the important thing is to be consistent across project, so should be chosen by the developers involved.

That said i would do the following:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String borrowBook(@RequestParam(value = "borrower_id", required = false) Long borrowerId,
            @RequestParam(value = "book_id", required = false) Long bookId){
        if(bookId == null || borrowerId == null){
            return "redirect:form.html";             
        }
        int result = borrowService.createBorrow(bookId, borrowerId);
        switch(result){
            case BorrowService.INVALID_ARG:
                return "redirect:form.html";
            case BorrowService.FAILURE:
                return "redirect:error.html";
            case BorrowService.SUCCESS:
                return "redirect:success.html";
            default:
                return "redirect:index.html";
        }              
    }
```

You should also reconsider why required is false for these mandatory parameters.

```
Service :
    public int createBorrow(Long bookId, Long borrowerId) {            
        Book book = getBookFromId(bookId);
        if(book == null){
            return INVALID_ARG;
        } 
        Borrower borrower = getBorrowerFromId(borrowerId);
        if(borrower == null){
            return INVALID_ARG;
        }
        try {
            Borrow borrow = new Borrow(book, borrower);
            markBookAsRented(book);
            setBorrowIntoEntities(borrow, book, borrower);
            persistEntities(borrow, book, borrower);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```